# unable to find the TestComponent in the error "Cannot determine the module for class TestComponent"

Tags: angular

I tried to build the project in production mode and got this error "Cannot determine the module for class TestComponent in `/home/int04wai/front/src/app/test/test.component.ts! Add TestComponent to the NgModule to fix it."`

I cannot find any files with keywork TestComponent. How can I do to trace and remove this error?

I swear that I never create this file so how can the compile see a file like this and tell me?

---

Answer (score 0):

i think you had created class "TestComponent" inside the file "test.component.ts" and missed to add it into "app.module.ts" declarations[ ] by importing it

```
import { TestComponent } from './....';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  declarations: [TestComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I tried to search for this file but cannot see / locate to. I'm not sure if I got the problem with the compiler.